# Blank Page after installation (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Hello sorry i want to ask something since i'm beginner in computer sciences so i want to use this project from github : https://github.com/senor-artemisio/kontroller8.

I'm already install by using

```
composer install && npm install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate to my SQL
```

so far no problem with this installation but after i want to open localhost, the website only show blank page. What's should i do ?

I don't know which one is the problem so i'm just gonna show my route code :

```
Route::any('{all}', 'AppController@index')->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

env file :

```html
APP_NAME=Kontroller8
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:YLVT7X8Jc6D5NtcgJ1p5eBuSmqxBxbMA3bcqQ4LsTHQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://kntrl8

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: hello @KevinY yes, i'm already do 'php artisan serve' after that it's only show blank page.

Comment: hye @KevinY i'm already create a htaccess in /public but still i got the same result.

Comment: nvm @KevinY i think i'm already know why the website only shows blank page because in /view it's doesn't have anything but i see at /js file it seem have vue files. do i need to install something to read vue files ?

Comment: Ah, yeah, the view is pretty light. It looks like a single page Javascript. You can run the mixin using `npm run prod` to generate the javascript it should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to run `npm run prod` (for production, i.e. it minifies the javascript)
or `npm run dev` (for development).
see https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#running-mix

This will run the code shown here:
https://github.com/senor-artemisio/kontroller8/blob/master/webpack.mix.js

Namely it would read from `resources/js/app.js` and output a webpacked version to `/public/js/app.js` along with `resources/sass/app.scss` to `/public/css/app.css`

https://github.com/senor-artemisio/kontroller8/blob/master/resources/js/app.js contains a bunch of code which would get generated etc.

Apparently the project doesn't include generated versions for you in the repo and make you generate it yourself.